# Big files containing several columns, export all the columns by naming them with the file name and a value

Tags: python

Thank you in advance for your answer !
I have lot of files wich contain columns.
I want to export all the columns separately in multiple files.
Moreover, I want to use the first value of each column to be the index of the file name.

For example. If I have the file "test_.dat" which contains 3 columns :

### 12  54  159

### 2    9   87

### 5   99  201

...
...

### 91   1  777

I want three files: "test_12.dat", "test_54.dat" & "test_159.dat".
Where "test_12.dat" is :

---

### 2

### 5

### ...

### ...

### 91

I know that I need to consider two loops (one for the initial files) and another one for the reading/export of the columns.
I know only how tu use append, but this is a very time consuming approach.
I would deeply appreciate your support.
Here is my try:

Find all ".dat" from a folder :

```
for fname in glob.glob(‘test_*.dat’):
    temp=numpy.loadtxt(fname,skiprows=2)
    data.append(temp)



namefiles=glob.glob('test*.dat')
```

Append all the columns together (Very long step):

```
for i in range (len(nomfichier)):
    for k in range (1,nbrechi+1):
        for j in range (points):
            ikj.append(data[i][j][k])
```

Define two variables to split the variables (points is the number of rows)

```
seq2=[ikj[i:i+points] for i in range(0, len(ikj), points)]
chunks = [ikj[points*i:points*(i+1)] for i in range(len(ikj)/points + 1)]
```

Export the columns in the specific files:

```
for j in range(len(nomfichier)):
    for i in range(len(seq2)/len(namefiles)):
            z=z+1
            savetxt(namefiles[j][:-4] + « _number_ » + str(flattened[i]) + ".dat", zip(firstcolumn,seq2[z]))
            print(namefiles[j][:-4] + « _number_ » + str(flattened[i]))
            zz.append(z)
```

Comment: you know how to do it, I know how I would do it, but that won't make me write some code because you have a performance requirement that I'm not getting. Can you share your code which you think is not performant so we can improve it?

Comment: How large do you expect the files to be? Will they fit in memory?

Comment: Thank you Jean-François Fabre & Realistic. In fact the files are too big. They do not fit the memory. I edited the question by puting some parts of my code. The append part is too slow and too big for the memory..

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to read the large file with `pandas`, it is designed for big data handling.

To read the data use the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.bat', sep='\s', engine='python', header=None)
```

to save the columns as individual files you can use the following code:

```
for ci in df.columns.values:
    data = df[ci]
    data.to_csv('test_{}.bat'.format(data[0]))
```

You can change the `sep` depending on what is used in your bat file. The defualt for pandas is a comma but in this case, like in your example data ,I used space. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you Neill Herbst. I will try your suggestion. Do you know how to increment the 'test_{}.bat' file by the name of the first row of each columns ?

Comment: @deezertsix when you run the code you will see that each file is saved with `{}` being replaced by the first element of each column.

Comment: Unfortunatly this is not working as expected. Do you have any suggestions to improve it ?

Comment: @deezertsix how is it failing? If you can give me some more detail maybe I can fix it. Also what version of python are you using?

Comment: @ Neill Herbst In fact it does create only one file. I use Python 2.7.12.

Comment: @deezertsix I think the problem is the separator pandas uses to read the data. Try changing it to something else.

Comment: @ Neill Herbst It does not evolve. Do you have any suggestions ? Thank you.

Comment: @deezertsix can you maybe edit your question to show your current pandas code maybe I can spot something. Also try using `sep='\t'`

Answer (score 0):

```
fps_out = []
with open('test_.dat', 'r') as fp_in:
    for line in fp_in:
        if not fps_out:
            for data in line.split():
                fps_out.append(open('test_%s.dat' % data, 'w'))
        else:
            for pos, data in enumerate(line.split()):
                fps_out[pos].write(data + '\n')

for fp in fps_out:
    fp.close()
```

Comment: @ John Gordon Thank you. I tried your lines and it says: NameError: name 'fp' is not defined

Comment: @ John Gordon. Thank you but it still does not work.

Comment: How does it not work?  Does it throw an exception?  Is the file output incorrect?